# A different meaning for the word shambhu

Tags: shiva, puranas

The meaning of shambhu is one who creates auspiciousness, Now if one speaks shambhu repeatedly it sounds like bhuSham which means ornament, which one can interpret as The lord shambhu is like the ornament of the world. Is this view present in any purana?

Comment: Not exactly related, but you may want to check this once: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/43689/647

Comment: No, Sha in Shambhu is small Sha, it is शंभु. But in Bhusham, it is big sha,  भूषं. So it is not the same.

Comment: yes, that's why I wrote similar @HariKumar